# WPF DataGrid: How do I access the DataRow a TextBox etc. resides in?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

So I have columns defined like this:

```
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=COLUMN_NAME, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

TextBox isn't the only control that may exist in the DataTemplate for a column, I have DateTimePickers, ComboBoxes, etc.

And what I want to do is define some style triggers like this that access some property in the DataRow:

```
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding  RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, 
                        Path=Row.RowState}" Value="Modified">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGreen" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```

Now unfortunately it would appear the TextBoxes are never logical children of DataGridRows. So what is the solution? Of course I can create a trigger that targets DataGridRows themselves, but this is redundant because setting the foreground property will do nothing (TextBoxes and other controls sit in front).

Any help most appreciated.
Fugu

EDIT: Here is the solution I chose, because RowState does not notify its listeners and extending DataRow is problematic.

1) Bind an event to the control(s) for when their data changes.
2) Refresh the Style to check for the RowState again:

```
        Style s = ((TextBox)sender).Style;
        ((TextBox)sender).Style = null;
        ((TextBox)sender).Style = s;
```

Obviously it will be made more generic than that.

edit 2: This blatantly won't work as I'd need to reset the style for each control individually, which even if it was possible would be a bad thing to do

Comment: Are you sure the RelativeSource binding is the problem? It could be that DataGridRow.Row.RowState is not accessible, or that the RowState is an enum that is being compared to a string, so always returns false. A simple test I like to use is setting the ToolTip to the RelativeSource to see if anything comes up at all.

Comment: Try this: http://www.codearsenal.net/2012/07/wpf-datagrid-rowdetailstemplate.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947918/wpftoolkit-datagrid-highlight-modified-rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947918/wpftoolkit-datagrid-highlight-modified-rows/4948029#4948029)

As far as the binding, `Row` isn't a property of `DataGridRow`, so you have to use `DataContext.Row.RowState`.

With that said, WPF is unable to detect changes to the `RowState` property, so your best bet is probably to wrap your items in a view model, rather than directly binding to the DataTable.

Comment: Thanks Jason. Because of the difficulty with detecting changes in RowState I have opted to use events to 'refresh' the style. Updated my post to reflect the solution I went for.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is `DataGridCell`, which can be styled. From memory the properties -should- be passed down to the `TextBox`

Comment: There is no 'Row' property in DataGridCell and it has the same problems when looking for the parent of TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a data template selector.  Create different data templates that contain your desired properties paired with text boxes and swap them around inside your data grid.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx