# WPF DataGrid DataTrigger Binding on DataContext property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, datatrigger

What's the correct DataTrigger binding for DataContext properties?
I have a DataGrid which is bound like this:

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    ItemsSource="{Binding}"
    CellStyle="{StaticResource RowStateStyle}"
>
</DataGrid>
```

In .cs the grid is bound to a DataTable, hence the DataContext for a cell is DataRowView, containing Row as a property:

```
// DataTable containing lots of rows/columns
dataGrid.DataContext = dataTable;
```

**Edit:**

Refering to ASh's solution I edited the style and put in Triggers for Unchanged and Modified:

```
    <Style x:Key="RowStateStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.Row.RowState,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Unchanged">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.Row.RowState,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Modified">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Content.Text,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="test">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Triggering on Content.Text works perfectly fine, so does Unchanged. However when I modify a cell (thus DataRowState = Modified), nothing happens and the color stays green. Any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DataTrigger works for me, if I

1. use `DataContext.Row.RowState` path
2. don't use `Mode=TwoWay`
3. and remove enum name `DataRowState` when set Value

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.Row.RowState,
             RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
             Value="Unchanged">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
</DataTrigger>
```

---

I have found another post related to this issue

[WpfToolkit DataGrid: Highlight modified rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947918/wpftoolkit-datagrid-highlight-modified-rows)

There is no default mechanism which notifies about `RowState` changes. But it is possible to create one in a derived dataTable class:

```
public class DataTableExt: DataTable
{
    protected override DataRow NewRowFromBuilder(DataRowBuilder builder)
    {
        return new DataRowExt(builder);
    }

    protected override void OnRowChanged(DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnRowChanged(e);
        // row has changed, notifying about changes
        var r = e.Row as DataRowExt;
        if (r!= null)
            r.OnRowStateChanged();
    }
}
```

with a derived dataRow class:

```
public class DataRowExt: DataRow, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected internal DataRowExt(DataRowBuilder builder) : base(builder)
    {
    }

    internal void OnRowStateChanged()
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("RowState");
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still not there yet. See my edited post.

Comment: @ray, my guess is that `DataRow` doesn't raise event or notification, when `RowState` changes. cannot check or suggest any fix now

Comment: when I "redraw" the grid (e.g. re-sorting), changes are visualized. So either a little hack: Redraw the row whenever a cell changes or maybe the solution [from here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798936/inotifypropertychanged-or-inotifycollectionchanged-with-datatable). However that will be very annoying instead of simple triggering an Event like DataGrid_CellEditEnding and just changes colors code-wise (just 3 lines of code). What do you say?

Comment: @ray, see my edit with some ideas. I keep forgetting a long, but type-safe way to use enums in xaml (*sigh*).

Comment: sry for my late reply. I've implemented the approach - for whatever reason, changes are still only visualized once the grid is being redrawn (sorting cols). I've debugged and all methods (OnRowStateChanged, OnPropertyChanged) are being called as expected. Hence I really do not understand why it's still not working. Another forum suggested to completely withdraw this approach and create classes instead of using a DataTable - also to pursue WPF's MVVM. What do you think?

Comment: @ray, `OnRowStateChanged` is called, but what `RowState` is it? maybe it is not what you expect. try add a column with RowState (for debug purposes) `<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Row.RowState}"/>` and see.

Comment: Disregard my comment. It's working like a charm. Thanks a bunch for helping me out. It's totally clear now, but I would've never got there myself.